# How to get selected item id,name or another json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am new on JSON and I'm still trying to learn that's why I have couple of question/issue.

edit: I achieved to redirect selected item..

I have simple basic autocomplete plugin [flexdatalist autocomplete](http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/) and I want to get selected item properties.

[Before you check the codes you can see my project online](http://firatabak.com/example/)

footnote: I couldn't achievement add on codepen or stackoverflow snippet because on this platform json data wasn't loaded.

my json file

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Name 1",
        "icon" : "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/finalflags/16/Germany-Flag.png",
        "address":"http://www.google.com",
        "category": "Premium",
        "area": "United States",
        "updated": null
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Name 2",
        "icon":"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/finalflags/16/China-Flag.png",
        "address":"http://www.youtube.com",
        "category": "Free",
        "area": "Spain",
        "updated": null
    }
]
```

as you see I have `address` and `icon` properties and I want to return this value I mean when I selected item from input than it must give me selected `address` and `icon`.

my js

```
    $('.flexdatalist').flexdatalist({
    cache:false,
    searchContain: false,
    textProperty: '{name},{continent}',
    valueProperty: 'address',
    minLength: 1,
    focusFirstResult: true,
    selectionRequired: true,
    groupBy: 'continent',
    visibleProperties: ["name", "continent", "capital_timezone"],
    searchIn: ["address","name", "continent"],
    url: 'hotels.json',
    relatives: '#relative'
}).on("select:flexdatalist",function(){
  window.location.href=this.value;
});
```

and my html

```
<input type='text' placeholder='Otel adını veya Bölgeyi yazmaya başla' class='flexdatalist'> <span></span>
```

and last question is how can I add icon/image left/right of item ? icons are in my json data

Comment: You can make a request to load your file into an array and then access the icons through stored data.

Comment: but how will I do that with autocomplete and I'm new on JSON it must be another way absolutely  and thanks for replying

Comment: I know how to access with jquery methot but I have to protect this structure because I'm using with autocomplete

Comment: Based on the docs I have just checked this library doesn't let you query images from the json file.If you want to check the address you can just add     `searchIn: ["address", "city"]` so that the queries would be based on the address value.

Comment: so I'm using `address` to redirect selected item I won't show it related result..so let's say I want to add images if I get data with autocomplete I couldn't add any image am I right ? interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all
You have to change the fields to match what you want to get
And if you want to change json string to images you have to use js

Please check out is this javascript works for you.

```
$('.flexdatalist').flexdatalist({
    cache:false,
    searchContain: false,
    textProperty: '{address},{icon}',
    valueProperty: 'iso2',
    minLength: 1,
    focusFirstResult: true,
    selectionRequired: true,
    groupBy: 'address',
    visibleProperties: ["address", "icon"],
    searchIn: ["address", "icon"],
    url: 'hotels.json',
    relatives: '#relative'
}).on("show:flexdatalist.results",function(ev,result){
    $.each(result,function(key,value){
        result[key]['icon_highlight'] = '<img src="'+value.icon+'">'; 
    })
});
```

Comment: oow thank but  this code doesn't give me  any result ?

Comment: do I have to use any word instead of `result` and `key` ?

Comment: Yes it's typo, use result instead res :)